# How to clone EC2 instance without updating packages

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Today I was creating new instances and I noticed something weird on it.
I used to select an old instance, then "launch more like this" and finally detaching the volume and attaching a volume from a snapshot of the instance I'm clonning.
Now, after the Instance is running I noticed my original php is 5.3.8 and the new Instance's one is 5.3.9.
I started checking if there is any auto-update service and I don't have any running.
Does someone know how to avoid the upgrade or why is this happening?

Comment: What EC2 region are you running in?  What AMI id did you start with?  If it is a private AMI, then what Linux distro?

Comment: The AMI is ami-8c1fece5 running in us-east-1c.
That's an standard amazon linux ami with some packages installed by yum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Linux uses `cloud-init` which performs various startup functions when an instance first boots.  One of these functions is to perform a software package upgrade to the level specified by the config parameter `repo_upgrade` in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` which appears to default to `security` in the AMI you reference.

It looks to me like there could be a bug in the `upgrade` sub in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cloudinit/DistAction/dist_repo_yum.py` which handles the repo upgrade as it seems to simply upgrade everything in the case of `UPGRADE_SECURITY`.

You may want to report this behavior to Amazon, perhaps through the [EC2 forum](http://ec2forum.notlong.com).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that config file. PHP 5.3.9 is posted in amazon site as vulnerability fixes, so I'm guess everything is working ok in the script.

Comment: Glancing at the code, I still think it might have a bug, even if it did the right thing in your case.